# Usb joystick detected... and removed

Tags: usb, udev, joystick

I have a strange issue where my usb joystick is detected properly and then nicely removed by the kernel.

dmesg output when inserting the usb connector:

```
[ 2319.770016] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 2319.880607] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5750
[ 2319.880609] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2319.880611] usb 1-1.5: Product: FALENCI
[ 2319.880613] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: FALENCI
[ 2319.880615] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 206739655233
[ 2319.882481] input: FALENCI FALENCI as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0009/input/input26
[ 2319.942381] hid-generic 0003:0483:5750.0009: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Gamepad [FALENCI FALENCI] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5/input0
```

However in the syslog I find:

```
Oct 17 23:25:51 Axe kernel: [ 2319.770016] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 23:25:51 Axe kernel: [ 2319.880607] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5750
Oct 17 23:25:51 Axe kernel: [ 2319.880609] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 17 23:25:51 Axe kernel: [ 2319.880611] usb 1-1.5: Product: FALENCI
Oct 17 23:25:51 Axe kernel: [ 2319.880613] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: FALENCI
Oct 17 23:25:51 Axe kernel: [ 2319.880615] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 206739655233
Oct 17 23:25:51 Axe kernel: [ 2319.882481] input: FALENCI FALENCI as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.0009/input/input26
Oct 17 23:25:51 Axe kernel: [ 2319.942381] hid-generic 0003:0483:5750.0009: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Gamepad [FALENCI FALENCI] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5/input0
Oct 17 23:25:51 Axe mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5"
Oct 17 23:25:51 Axe mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Oct 17 23:25:51 Axe acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 16
```

and using `udevadm monitor` I get:

```
KERNEL[2849.850516] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5 (usb)
KERNEL[2849.850688] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[2849.851478] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A (hid)
KERNEL[2849.852165] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27 (input)
KERNEL[2849.912343] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27/event2 (input)
KERNEL[2849.912420] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27/js0 (input)
KERNEL[2849.912565] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
KERNEL[2849.912616] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2849.934209] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5 (usb)
UDEV  [2849.936100] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2849.937515] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A (hid)
UDEV  [2849.938171] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [2849.940255] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
KERNEL[2849.992217] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27/event2 (input)
KERNEL[2850.008233] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27/js0 (input)
KERNEL[2850.032209] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27 (input)
KERNEL[2850.032252] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
KERNEL[2850.032317] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
KERNEL[2850.032347] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A (hid)
UDEV  [2850.033024] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2850.033116] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [2850.033273] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27 (input)
UDEV  [2850.034723] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27/event2 (input)
UDEV  [2850.035337] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27/event2 (input)
UDEV  [2850.036645] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27/js0 (input)
UDEV  [2850.037334] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27/js0 (input)
UDEV  [2850.037954] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A/input/input27 (input)
UDEV  [2850.038398] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0483:5750.000A (hid)
```

I do appreciate the system cleaning up after itself, but I would like to use it a bit in between :-(

The setup worked previously without problems, thought this was while running 16.04 instead of 17.04

Anyone a suggestion what could be going wrong or which way to go to debug this problem?

**EDIT:**
I have debugged a bit more and found a probable cause of my misery/mystery.
When exporting the udev database using `udevadm info -e` I find the following about my device:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5
N: bus/usb/001/011
E: BUSNUM=001
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/011
E: DEVNUM=011
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MODEL=FALENCI
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=FALENCI
E: ID_MODEL_ID=5750
E: ID_REVISION=0200
E: ID_SERIAL=FALENCI_FALENCI_206739655233
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=206739655233
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_VENDOR=FALENCI
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=FALENCI
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=STMicroelectronics
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0483
E: MAJOR=189
E: MINOR=10
E: PRODUCT=483/5750/200
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=8384101306

P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0
E: DEVTYPE=usb_interface
E: DRIVER=usbfs
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=STMicroelectronics
E: INTERFACE=3/0/0
E: MODALIAS=usb:v0483p5750d0200dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc00ip00in00
E: PRODUCT=483/5750/200
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=8384114545
```

However usbfs is an obsolete driver which is not a module on my system. Because the driver does not exist it can not be blacklisted.
I checked if there was any mention to this driver in the existing udev rules in lib and etc, but there aren't. Cleaning the database using `udevadm info -c` removes it from the list, but it is back there the moment I retry to plug in the device.

So, where does this usbfs come from, and more importantly how to remove it from the hwdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought this seems a bit a workaround, I'll post my (temporary?) solution anyway since for now it fixes my problem.

I use `usb_modeswitch` to detach the non-functional driver and reset the usb:

> usb_modeswitch -v VID -p PID -d -R

exchange `VID`  and `PID` to the values given to you by `lsusb`. The numbers after ID are `VID:PID`